# Images don't load on browser when sending HTTP response via a C HTTP server

Tags: c, image, http, server

I have been trying for several days to fix my problem with images not showing up on the browser, the index.html loads fine, the css and js aswell and the only image format that loads is .svg
All the headers are well initialwed and correct.

I have tried most of the suggestions in the forums, such  as us memcpy instead of strcat, fread to load a file into the buffer using binary read ("rb" option) and such.

Here is the code that copies the file's contents into the message body:
(sorry for the stuff in french)

```c
void server_fileToSend(char* file, int len, char* rep, char* header,
                       char* message_body) {
    char* body_size_char = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    char* filename = (char*)calloc(100, sizeof(char));
    char* sendbody;

    if (file[0] == '/') {
        strncpy(filename, file + 1, len - 1);
    } else {
        strncpy(filename, file, len);
    }
    // printf(" filetruc %s\n",filename);
    FILE* f = fopen(filename, "rb+");
    if (f == NULL) {
        // Modification du type de réponse
        strcpy(rep, "HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND\r\n");
        f = fopen("sites/notfound.html", "r");
    }
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    body_size = ftell(f);
    rewind(f);
    strcat(header, "Content-Length: ");
    sprintf(body_size_char, "%ld", body_size);
    strcat(header, body_size_char);
    strcat(header, "\r\n");

    if (f != NULL && findContentType(filename) != NULL) {
        strcat(header, findContentType(filename));
    }
    strcat(header, "Connection: keep-alive\r\n");

    if ((sendbody = (char*)malloc(body_size)) == NULL) {
        memcpy(message_body, "this is a directory", 20);
        body_size = 20;
    } else {
        result = fread(sendbody, 1, body_size, f);
        if (result > 0) {
            memcpy(message_body, sendbody, body_size);
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

And after that I append the message_body into the response, after the headers with :

```c
memcpy(rep+strlen(rep),message_body, body_size);
```

There are no actual errors, the page loads fine, it's just that all images except .svg don't load. Also when I inspect them with the web developper mode of firefox, the images are only a few bytes and the dimensions are 0x0.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Edit 1 :
Here are some Requests from firefox and Responses respectively :

For index.html

```
#########################################
Demande recue depuis le client 9
Client [9] [127.0.0.1:46918]
Contenu de la demande GET /www.toto.com/index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Cache-Control: max-age=0


-----------Réponse-------------------
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Wed, 05 Jun 2019 07:32:39 GMT
Server: groupe15 (Debian9)
Content-Length: 621
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
<script src="index.js"></script> 
<title>Index page</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a all images i have got so far !!! </h1>
<img onmouseover="big(this)" src="index.gif" alt="gif"> 
<img onmouseover="big(this)" src="index.png" alt="png"> 
<img onmouseover="big(this)" src="index.svg" alt="svg"> 
<img onmouseover="big(this)" src="index.jpg" alt="jpg"> 
<img onmouseover="big(this)" src="index.jpeg" alt="jpeg"> 
<img onmouseover="big(this)" src="index.tif" alt="tif"> 
<img onmouseover="big(this)" src="index.tiff" alt="tiff"> 

</body>
</html>
```

For an image:

```
#########################################
Demande recue depuis le client 8
Client [8] [127.0.0.1:46926]
Contenu de la demande GET /www.toto.com/index.png HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0
Accept: image/webp,*/*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost:8080/www.toto.com/index.html
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0

-----------Réponse-------------------
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Wed, 05 Jun 2019 07:32:39 GMT
Server: groupe15 (Debian9)
Content-Length: 2574
Content-Type: image/png
Connection: keep-alive

�PNG
```

As you can see, the problem lies in the message body

Comment: Welcome to SO. Did you check the header you prepared? You could simply print it before you add the body. Or you could capture the packet using Wireshark etc.. Does the string returned by your `findContentType` contain `"\r\n"`?

Comment: What is the real size of the images? How much memory is available at `*messagebody`. Why do you use `sendbody` if you copy to `message_body` anyway? How does the calling function know how much data to send?

Comment: @Gerhardh findcontenttype does Contain a "\r\n"
The message body is a malloc of 10MB, i use sendbody because I don't like direclty modifying parameters, at least I've benn taught that it's bad

Comment: What is the difference compared to using `messagebody` directly? What can fail at this point is allocating the very same memory that you wouldn't need if you used `messagebody` instead.

Comment: But still you need to get the `body_size` out of that function.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I note that you are not freeing the memory you allocate for `body_size_char` and `filename`.

Comment: I did what you suggested, I used fread direclty on message_body, but still only svg loads, the png, jpg and tif don't

Comment: Should I add '\0' in the end of my char* variables ?

Comment: I have freed the memories at the end

Comment: @TDLaouer: when you use `calloc()` the memory is initialized to zero - so no need to explicitly add a NULL character. That is not the case when you use `malloc()` however.
Having said that .. I think you are over-complicating things by using dynamic memory here. I would just declare `body_size_char` and `filename` on the stack rather than the heap.

Comment: I don't see you adding the `HTTP` status line in the case that the image file is loaded successfully. Should you not be using a `strcpy(rep, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK")` in that case?

Comment: Please add the generated HTTP-header to the question.

Comment: `strncpy` does not add a terminating `\0` if the string pointed to by `file` is longer than 100 bytes.

Comment: For test (index.html) the sending function could simply use `strlen` to get the length of data to be sent. It is still missing how you provide the length for images to the caller. I assume you simply do not send enough data to the client. How long was the transmitted packet for the PNG? AFAIK SVG file format is XML based, i.e. pure text.

Comment: The length is provided by the function ftell(f) once I'm done with FSEEK, this normally seeks the end of the file, which is the size, and I put it in the body_size variable, thus obtaining the size of the image, normally. Then I rewind to go back to the beginning of the file.

Comment: That happens inside the function you show us. But this does not send any data. Sending must be done by the caller function. How would that function know what the nested cann to `ftell` returned to you? `body_size` is not known outside that function. As mentioned above a few times: How do you get this information out of that function?

Comment: body_size is a global variable, and i do the memcpy to a variable in the parameter, which is in my case a pointer outside of the function outside of the function. And the caller clearly gets something

Comment: OK, does your server handle multiple connections? A global variable might be a problem there.